# Transfer file when receiver is offline in XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp

How to transfer file when receiver is offline in XMPPP Protocol? Which extension have to use? Any sample code available for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store file somewhere and send link as described in [Out Of Band Data](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0066.html) extension. Message will be delivered when recipient will be online.

Comment: Good idea. Is this tried and tested form your side?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that your receiver is offline. So If receiver is offline than you have to upload your message to your server using web service. And your receiver have to get all offline messages using web service after xmpp stream connect.

This is best way for offline message. Please do like this and let me know if any problem.